# Django URL Conf/Reverse Lookup: Introducing new kwarg to left side of url

Tags: python, django

I am trying to introduce a new kwarg to the front/left of a set of namespaced urls in django. Basically I want to go from this:

```
domain.com/products/kwarg1/kwarg2/etc
```

to this:

```
domain.com/kwarg0/products/kwarg1/kwarg2/etc
```

Thanks to django's urlconf and namespacing, actually changing the urls is easy. However, I am working on a codebase that has a significant number of reverse() url lookups. Ex:

```
url = reverse('product:category',
                   kwargs={'kwarg1': self.get_full_path(ancestors),
                           'kwarg2': self.id})
```

Does anyone know if there is a canonical way of introducing kwarg0 into my urls *without* finding every single reverse() url lookup and inserting an appropriate argument for kwarg0?

Comment: But if you're not adding kwarg0 to your reverse calls, what value do to want it to take?

Comment: Right. I guess I was hoping there might be some kind of urlconf lookup middleware that I wasn't aware of that would allow me to modify all reverse() lookups. As of now all I can think of is writing a wrapper reverse() function that acts in this manner.